# Subscribe to a PubNub Channel using PHP

Tags: php, pubnub

If I subscribe to a PubNub Channel using PHP will it stay subscribe for ever until the server is restarted or will eventually timeout and unsubscribe on its own?

Example code bellow:

```
$pubnub->subscribe(array(
    'channel' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'callback' => function ($message) {
            //do stuff
            return true;
        }
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the callback return false will break the loop / return control. More info here:

https://github.com/pubnub/php#receive-message-subscribe

Comment: One more question. I figured out that the reason why it will stop sometimes was because apache was restarted, and therefore the script will stop running. How can I make it run after apache restarts again. So it will always be running. Even if the server itself is also restarted.

Comment: You would need a script using something like curl or wget auto run after apache starts. Otherwise, just create a .php script that can be run on machine startup, that will always run, regardless if apache is running.